# Using same data twice in a machine-learning model

Tags: r, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, sentiment-analysis

I am working on a machine learning problem with 37 features to learn from.

So the method I plan on using is as follows:

1) I do a sentiment prediction on 17 of these features to output {negative, neutral, positive}.

2) Then use 20 + 1(sentiment) features to make my final prediction.

So is it correct if I use the same training data set for both the steps? OR Should I use different data sets for both the steps? If so, why?

Comment: It is correct to use the same data.  Picture this way: you are doing a feature transformation in the first step (from 17 dimensions to 1 dimension), and using this new feature in your model.  I am curious why you were concerned about data reuse for both the steps.

Comment: What are you trying to predict with is your final prediction in step 2? I assume it is not the same as step 1 (i.e. {negative, neutral, positive}).

Comment: Yes, final predication is different.